# How can i smooth out the surface of this smoke simulation?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

im currently trying to morph smoke from one shape to another using keyed particles and the flow source of my smoke set to the particle system.
So far i was able to simulate the motion but the smoke render looks a bit weird:

[image]

As you can see the smoke has roughly the shape of suzanne the monkey, though i would like it to have less of those ripples on the surface and more detail around the eyes.

I tried a few things like higher density, bigger particle size in simulation cells (or smaller) but it always has those ripples on the surface.
Here is my current node system of the domain:

[image]

I have to say im not even sure whether or not this is the right approach for this. Im not a professional artist (just a programmer trying basic stuff in blender). I appreciate any useful feedback!

Comment: Did you try using nurbs as particle mesh?

Comment: Im not sure as why using another particle mesh could help solving this because what you see is not the particle itself but the smoke which is emmited where the particles are located.

Comment: the nurbs would merge with each other and by controlling the nurb size you can probably eliminate those ripples.